Render Chinese characters correctly in iOS
I have certain Chinese text in my app that I want to make sure appears in regular script. It currently renders like this on the phone:

However, I want it to render like this so that it looks more natural:

I've tried setting the font on my Text component.
Text(text)
   .font(.custom("STHeiti", size: 24))

Regardless, it shows up as intended on the computer (i.e. in the SwiftUI preview section). But I cannot get it to render as intended on the phone.
This post explains the issue generically, but I haven't been able to find a fix.
iOS version 17.5

Are you sure STHeiti is installed on the phone? Try PingFang SC instead.

@Sweeper you're spot on, it was not installed. Using PingFang SC worked like a charm, thanks!

As you may know, this is merely a font difference. The system font chooses which font to use depending on the language & region settings. If you set your phone's region to mainland China and language to Simplified Chinese, you should see the correct form. The undesirable form of 包 you see is the standard form for Japan.
Compare the images from zdic.net,
 
If you want it to appear the same for all users regardless of their language & region settings, you can set the font explicitly like in your attempt. As far as I know, the default font for simplified Chinese since iOS 9 is "PingFang SC", not "STheiti".
.font(.custom("PingFang SC", size: 24))


In HTML you can also explicitly set the language for any element to force the correct script without resorting to hardcoded font names. Is there something like that in Swift?

@nneonneo I had that same thought too, and I tried .environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "zh-CN")) but it didn't do anything.
